# Find the hidden dialogue

Tags: cipher

26535-34825-69399-78164-50288  59230-26433
70679-41971-14159-78164-06286-34211

Hint 1:

> hyphens are letter-breaks, spaces are word-breaks.

Hint 2:

> it translates into a dialogue from a recent and popular marvel movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is (I think):

> Bring me Thanos.

process:

> The letters are decimals after PI.
>  
>  Every five numbers are a letter, the position is the position in the alphabet.
>  
>  26535 = B
>  
>  pi=3.14159 **26535** 89793 23846 26433 83279 50288 41971
>  
>  26535 is the 2nd block of 5 numbers

Comment: your answer was correct as well as the process. nicely done.

Comment: could you please give more explanation about your process?

Comment: @malioboro: I've improved my explanation.

Comment: BTW, @OfFPiR was this too easy?

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid, Not really sure. I just got lucky that the number sequences looked familiar :)